# android accessing resources in menu folder

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

i'm using actionbarsherlock and i declared my menu in actionbar.xml in the menu folder. here's the content of actionbar.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/abSearch" android:showAsAction="always" android:icon="@drawable/search_orange"></item>
</menu>
```

now i tried to implement onOptionsItemSelected and here's what I did:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.abSearch:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchRecipes.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        }
    }
```

but the problem is eclipse says abSearch cannot be resolved. I tried cleaning the projects many times but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
android.R.id.abSearch
```

With:

```
R.id.abSearch
```